# Оптимизация запроса postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, оптимизация

Есть таблица table с полями groupField и count.

groupField - integer, принимает одно из N значений (N порядка единиц)

count - integer, положительное.

Таблица проиндексирована по groupField.

Количество записей в таблице - порядка десятка миллионов, записи распределены равномерно по groupField.

Нужно мне получить результат следующего запроса:

```
SELECT groupField FROM table GROUP BY groupField HAVING SUM(count) > :X
```

, где Х - параметр - число порядка единицы.

Очевидно, что postgres будет выполнять seq scan. Но, так как числа в колонке count положительные, то можно получить тот же результат, просмотрев примерно N*X строк, т.е. примерно в 100000 раз быстрее. Для этого нужно по каждому значению groupField смотреть не более X строк.

Вопрос: как вежливо попросить postgres (9.6) это сделать?

ЗЫ: Есть вариант решения с хардкодом значений groupField, благо их немного:

```
SELECT
  groupField,
  SUM(count) > X
FROM
  table
WHERE
  groupField = :groupFieldValue
LIMIT 7
```

Такие запросы можно написать для каждого значения groupField и затем заджойнить. Но такой хардкод делать по понятным причинам не очень хочется.

ЗЫЫ: таблица table получена с помощью WITH-а из реальной таблицы путем применения множества фильтров. Вариантов набора фильтров очень-очень много, набор фильтров примерно уникален для каждого запроса, соответственно, предрасчитать значения в table, и тем более значение результата, не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 0):

Может в момент получения таблицы через WITH добавить столбец с row_number?

```
SELECT groupField FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY groupField) AS rn, * FROM original_table
) x WHERE rn <= 7 
GROUP BY groupField HAVING SUM(count) > :X
```

Comment: Проверил. Не помогает. После получения таблицы  Для применения условия 'WHERE rn <= :X' postgres сканирует весь получившийся результат подзапроса (по факту это моя же таблица table, только с добавленной колонкой rn). На всякий случай добавил в подзапрос ORDER BY rn, но это тоже не помогло.

Comment: Попробуй творчески переработать: http://charlesnagy.info/it/postgresql/group-by-limit-per-group-in-postgresql